# crash from swift 4.0 to swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, crash

When I upgrade to Xcode 9.3. And I use Swift 4.1 compile my app. I found that the app crash in follow case:

```
xx.swift 
@objc func doSomething(_ stuff: Any) {
    print("do")
}

yy.m
// call swift function
doSomething(nil)    // crash in swift 4.1 but ok in swift 4.0
```

**I know how to modify the code.**

**I just want to know where I can get the information. Where the swift source code or information tell the different change?**

Comment: You can see the change log of the Swift here `https://swift.org/blog/swift-4-1-released/`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I amazed how it worked in swift 4. It must a crash. Now see your func

```
@objc func doSomething(_ stuff: Any) { // here stuff is not optional
    print("do")
}
```

and you calling it with `nil`

```
doSomething(nil)
```

It never works in any swift. So to correct it by making `stuff` as optional

```
@objc func doSomething(_ stuff: Any?) { 
        print("do")
    }
```

Now compile your code again.

Comment: I know how to modify the code. I just want to know where I can get the information about the different change.

Comment: It is run time error buddy, at compile scode never calls the func so it never know what value is upcoming,

Comment: Yep, the code run ok in swift 4.0. And swift 4.1 fix the bug. I want to know where the bug issue? And how to fix it, where the fix code? I cannot find it in swift.org.

Comment: @tutu_magi it is run time error so it crash your project and reason will be shown in console. Only compiler error will be shown at that time and gives you different suggestions to make your code correct. **EG** Take a variable `var abc : String = "abd"` now whenever you trying to nil this value it will gives you suggestion to correct bcz it is compile error.

Answer (score 0):

It will crash. As when you are calling the function, you are passing nil value to it. But in the function definition, `stuff` is a non optional variable. So write the function as below-

```
xx.swift 
@objc func doSomething(_ stuff: Any?) {
    print("do")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the stuff param to an optional:

```
@objc func doSomething(_ stuff: Any?) {
    print("do")
}
```

[Here's some reading about how optionals work.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)